# Need help on DateTime Conversion in Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am facing problem in DateTime converstion.
My input is 09/22/2011, I need to convert into 20110922.

I tried the below one, but failed.
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),'09/22/2011' , 112) as DateConv

Comment: Your input format looks like a string rather than a `datetime`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SET DATEFORMAT mdy
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CAST('09/22/2011' as DATETIME) , 112) AS DateConv
```

If your input is actually a dateTime variable like you said (but didn't show in your code example), you can simplify this down to:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @myDate  , 112) AS DateConv
```

Comment: Fails under `SET DATEFORMAT dmy` just like mine!

Comment: How about that (edit)? Cheating? My original version assumed the date string would be in the local format.

Comment: The OP has clarified that it is a `datetime` anyway so both your answers don't need the ambiguously formatted string literal and ought to work.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

`select year('09/22/2011') * 10000 + month('09/22/2011') * 100 + day('09/22/2011')`

Comment: Aaron that's because 20110922 IS an INT :D

Comment: Yes, understood. Just wanted to clarify because usually when formatting takes place for presentation the expected outcome is a string.

Comment: And in addition to DATEFORMAT this approach will also fail under SET LANGUAGE e.g. FRENCH. Not relevant for this specific question (now that we have more info) but just something to keep in mind in general. At least if you know the incoming string is m/d or d/m you can attempt to convert to datetime using style 101 or 103. If you just throw YEAR() at it you can't be sure it will always work.

Answer (score 0):

Without any other information, SQL is interpreting the '09/22/2011' as a varchar already, and just passes the data through (ignoring `CONVERT`'s style argument). If you use the following line:

```
SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR (8), CAST ('09/22/2011' as DATETIME), 112) as DateConv
```

it should work as expected since it will then view the '09/22/2011' as a date value. If you were getting the date from a column in a table, it would already know the type and you will not need to worry about the `CAST` portion of the expression, just use the column name.